# How can I get all of my keys and mouse to work using Midnight Commander on OSX?

Tags: macos, port, midnight-commander

I used *port* to install it and I figured out how to fix *home/end/pgup/pgdn* in the terminal preferences, but still,

- none of the keypad keys work.
- the mouse doesn't work.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.